# Why command not found in a specific folder?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a .sh file in bin folder, but when I try to use it, the server cannot find it in the folder.

```
/home/monju/full/app/bin $ls
checkServer.sh  etf_disagg_config_loader.sh  getLogName.sh  mapr
common.sh       findLog.sh                   jgrouplog.sh   phase2b
commonStart.sh  findServer.sh                jmx            postInstallSetup.sh
errorLog.ksh    followLog.sh                 jrebel.sh      probe.sh
etf             genTestFile.ksh              killServer.sh  RMSDisable.sh
/home/monju/full/app/bin $stopServer.sh
bash: stopServer.sh: command not found
```

while when I use `/home/monju/full/app/bin/stopServer.sh`, it can be used.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just because it's in a directory named `bin` doesn't mean the shell can magically find it.

You need to put the full path in your `$PATH` environment variable, or symlink it to somewhere that's in the `$PATH` already.

Of course, if you *only* want to run it from the current directory, it's best to use

```
$ ./stopServer.sh
```

Which is the same as the long absolute path you gave, only using relative path syntax where `.` means current directory.

Putting `.` itself in `$PATH` is considered bad practice.

Comment: It is *extra* bad practice to have it in the front of `$PATH` as anything in the current directory will be picked up before the standard search paths are used.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
./stopServer.sh
```

and make sure you have execution rights.